# How do I search a txt document for a word and write that word to a new document for reporting?

Tags: c#, cpu-word, text-files

I am trying to look through a log `.txt` file and find all instances of an ERROR message, and then have the code paste that error line in a new document using C#, and essentially create a separate `.txt` file with only the error lines from the log file listed.

I understand how to search for the text in the document using C#, but what would be the best way to approach extracting those error messages (that are typically no longer than 1-2 lines each) without appending the entire rest of the document after the first error instance?

**EDIT**

The log file logs the events on each line, and the error lines are read as follows:

```
Running install update (3)
ERROR: Running install update(3) (ERROR x34293) The system was unable to update the application, check that correct version is accessible by the system.
Running install update (4)
```

etc.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: It would help if we could see an example of the input, and an example of the expected output

Comment: It's very difficult to formulate an answer without seeing examples of your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filename)
                        .Where(l => l.Contains("ERROR MESSAGE")))
{
    // Log line
}
```

Additionally if you need specific information inside the line you can use a [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to capture the information. I cannot provide a better example without more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the file via RegEx pattern, which gives you either character position found, or line number (can't remember). Then you can grab that portion that is returned from the RegEx.

Here's a block of code from my own "Find And Replace" program I wrote that uses RegEx. There are some nested methods, but you get the point...

```
int foundInThisFile;
string regExPattern = FindText;
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regSearch = null;

if (IgnoreCase)
    regSearch = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regExPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
else
    regSearch = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regExPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection regExMatches = regSearch.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd());

            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Dispose();
                reader = null;
            }

            found += regExMatches.Count;
            TotalMatches(new CountEventArgs(found));

            foundInThisFile = regExMatches.Count;
            MatchesInThisFile(new CountEventArgs(foundInThisFile));

            if (regExMatches.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in regExMatches)
                {
                    // The first "group" is going to be the entire regex match, any other "group" is going to be the %1, %2 values that are returned
                    // Index is the character position in the entire document
                    if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
                    {
                        // This means the user wants to see the grouping results
                        string[] groupsArray = new string[match.Groups.Count - 1];

                        for (int counter = 1; counter < match.Groups.Count; counter++)
                            groupsArray[counter - 1] = match.Groups[counter].Value;

                        int lineNumber = 0;
                        string actualLine = String.Empty;

                        GetLineNumberAndLine(localPath, match.Groups[0].Index, out lineNumber, out actualLine);

                        AddToSearchResults(localPath, lineNumber, actualLine, groupsArray);

                        NewSearchResult(new SearchResultArgs(new FindReplaceItem(localPath, lineNumber, actualLine, ConvertGroupsArrayToString(groupsArray))));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int lineNumber = 0;
                        string actualLine = String.Empty;

                        GetLineNumberAndLine(localPath, match.Groups[0].Index, out lineNumber, out actualLine);

                        AddToSearchResults(localPath, lineNumber, actualLine);

                        NewSearchResult(new SearchResultArgs(new FindReplaceItem(localPath, lineNumber, actualLine)));
                    }
                }
            }
```